# How to stop or break the code execution without failing the test for a certain condition

Tags: java, selenium

```
public String checkIfReportingFromAvailable(){
        String locatorBuilder = "";
        List<WebElement> listOfRecords = driver.findElements(reportingFromField);
        List<WebElement> listOfPages = driver.findElements(recordPages);
        if (listOfRecords.size() <= 5 && listOfRecords.size() > 0 && listOfPages.size() == 0) {
                for (int i = 0; i < listOfRecords.size(); i++) {
                    String counter = Integer.toString(i + 1);
                    if (driver.findElement(By.xpath("//tbody/tr[" + counter + "][@class='ng-scope']//td[7]//span")).getText().equalsIgnoreCase("")) {
                        locatorBuilder = Integer.toString(i + 1);
                        break;
                    } else if (i == listOfRecords.size() - 1) {
                        //System.exit(); // Want to stop the execution if condition meets.
                    }
                }
            }
}

public EditCappingWindow clickEditCappingButton(){
        driver.findElement(By.xpath("//tbody/tr[" + checkIfReportingFromAvailable() + "][@class='ng-scope']//button[@tooltip='Edit Capping']")).click();
        for (String winHandle : driver.getWindowHandles()) {
            driver.switchTo().window(winHandle);
        }
        return new EditCappingWindow(driver);
    }
```

Calling checkIfReportingFromAvailable inside the clickEditCappingButton method. and clickEditCappingButton will be called in test and there are few lines of code afterwards. but my requirement is to stop the the code as mentioned above in checkIfReportingFromAvailable and test should pass.

Comment: That depends on how you determine your test passed or failed

Comment: Topping @Alexey R, `stop the execution if the condition meets`... If 'execution' here refers to the function: `checkIfReportingFromAvailable`, then you may use a `break`. If 'execution' here refers to exiting the entire test, then you may use `'break` followed by`driver.close()` or `driver.quit()`. Additionally, you may wrap the code in `try/catch` mechanism